# Triple monitor setup on GPU and MOBO

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, gpu

So, I have an AMD 7870 Sapphire OC Edition. It only has two DVI slots, HDMI and a display port. Anyway, I have two 1080p IPS panels setup to my main monitors, these are both connected to the GPU via DVI. However, I wanted to add my old monitor (720p) to it, just to place Skype, or to use as additional space when programming. I went into my Asus MOBO's BIOS and set iGPU to enabled, this allowed me to connect my 720p monitor as it only accepts VGA ports. So now I have two DVIs in my GPU and 1 VGA in my MOBO. It's all running fine, I just wondered if it would hinder my RAM's performance because it takes it up for gRAM. I don't think it'll be worth it if  I can't use my PC as intended. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're just bragging :P Seriously, I have 2 x 2k monitors hanging off an HD 5770 & it really doesn't seem to lag any more than when I had just one. I'd say, 'see how it feels' rather than rely on numbers, anyway.

Comment: I'm not bragging, my setup sucks. It's a mid-range setup. The reason I'm concerned is because I spend a lot of my time gaming, and if having a little monitor for nothing special hindering my performance, it's not worth it.

Comment: I was joking, hence the [:P] at the end - but my main point still stands... see how it feels. If no apparent hit, go with it; if it lags, drop the idea.

Comment: Unless you are gaming on the 720p monitor with high textures, your ram usage would not be significant. Also some motherboards allow you to limit the ram assigned to the iGPU. Again as @Tetsujin says if you do not hit any ram limits, you are golden.